# Flip image with different size width smooth transition

Tags: animation, libgdx, sprite, draw

I'm trying to flip some animations in LibGDX, but because they are of different width, the animation plays weird. Here's the problem:

(the red dot marks the X/Y coordinate {0,0})

[image]

As you can see, when the animation plays "left" when you punch, the feet starts way behind than were it was, but when you punch right, the animations plays fine because the origin of both animations is the left corner, so the transition is smooth.

The only way I think of achieving what I want is to see what animation is playing and adjust the coordinates accordingly.

This is the code:

```
public static float draw(Batch batch, Animation animation, float animationState,
        float delta,
        int posX, int posY, boolean flip) {
    animationState += delta;
    TextureRegion r = animation.getKeyFrame(animationState, true);
    float width = r.getRegionWidth() * SCALE;
    float height = r.getRegionHeight() * SCALE;

    if (flip) {
        batch.draw(r, posX + width, posY, -width, height);
    } else {
        batch.draw(r, posX, posY, width, height);
    }

    return animationState;
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome as how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some other batch.draw option (with other parameters). You can set "origin" parameters. It's like a hot spot...center of the image... So if you i.e. rotate, rotation will be done around that hot spot.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html

I didn't use it for flipping, but it should work the same way. But if it doesn't then you have to adjust coordinates on your own, make some list with X offset for every frame and add it for flipped images.

Other solution would be to have wider frame images and keep center of the character always match the center of the image. That way your images will be wider then they have to - you'll have some empty space, but for sane number of frame it's acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting the originX but I couldn't get it to work very well. I had some results using a static width (the width when the character is idle) and trying to adjust the others sprites to the center of it, but some animations render OK and others off-center. I'll try setting all the sprites to the same width as you said, but there are 65 in total.

Comment: You tried setting originX and originY, right? Not sure that it can work with setting only one value...

Comment: Yes. As you can see here [link](http://i.imgur.com/dgowc3z.png) the feet, which is what gives you the feel of transition between images is always off center from frame to frame and there's no way to center it with one value only. I tried several different ways (even make all frames the same width/size) and when I fix one animation, other becomes broken because of this. I think the better solution is to make an offset of every frame by hand, which is not something I like to do :(

Comment: I packed the textures with the texture packet that comes with LibGDX and I tried setting the offset manually inside the .pack file, but it doesn't seem to change anything. I guess i'll use another packer that I'm familiar with for this, but it's a shame because the animation and textureregion classes are very easy to use.

Comment: If you have packer that supports offsets that would be great. Didn't know that it even exists. But if not you have to measure hotspot offsets on your own (from Photoshop or something) and then make some kind of array with offset pairs for every frame which will you add to when rendering frame.

Comment: Yes. I ended up doing that: using Photoshop and aligning every frame. It's faster than writing my own library to use the other packer.